# How to record on a smartphone using XLR mic and guitar simultaneously?

Tags: audio-recording, multichannel, android

I have a fast track pro that I'm trying to record vocals and guitar with using my Samsung Galaxy S5.  I can connect the instruments to the fast track and plug it in and that's all fine and well, but how do I then connect the fast track to the smartphone?

Ideally, I'd be able to record vocals on one track and guitar on another track simultaneously (using N-Track, for example) but in the worst case scenario, I can accept them recorded onto one track, I suppose.

If I can't get them recorded on separate tracks with this setup (using a Fast Track Pro), is there any setup with which I can get my vocals recorded on one track on an Android app and my guitar, recorded at the same time, recorded on a second track in the same app?

Basically, I want to strum and sing while recording them as two separate tracks on a smartphone (Samsung S5).  Is it possible?  How does one do it?

Please.  And thank you!

Comment: as no-one's picked up on this one yet; first things you'd need to find would be compatible cables & a driver for the android [if one exists]. Maybe something like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbaudiorecorderpro&hl=en but I have neither fast track nor droid, so I've no direct experience

Answer (score 1):

You could look into something like this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.extreamsd.usbaudiorecorderpro&hl=en